# Can I create smaller pandas dataframes based on blocks of sequences of equal column values without iterating on rows?

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas dataframe: How can I create smaller dataframes by groups of similar column values without iterating row by row?

Picture a dataframe that has a column named "col". The contents of that column are ['A','B','A','A']. I want to go through this column and extract smaller dataframes associated with each grouping of 'A's. The output should be two dataframes. One which contains just row one, and then another with rows 3 and 4

There are ways to loop through the dataframe row by row, identifying the rows in which repetition occurs in groups. I would prefer not to loop through the dataframe as this is slow and generally frowned upon as far as I know.

Comment: Could you share a sample code?